# How to match Date & TimeStamp Field as a Text in typeorm Query Builder?

Tags: date, nestjs, typeorm, sql-like

I am building new query of searching text from table from `postgresql` database & `Nest JS` with `Typeorm`.

### My Query  :

```
var search_text = "04:45";

var query = this.Account.createQueryBuilder()
            .where('created_at ilike :search', { search: `%${search_text}%` });
```

### My Table Schema :

```
@Entity('Account')
export class AccountEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: Number;

    @Column({ collation: "default", nullable: true })
    code: string;

    @Column({ collation: "default" })
    firstname: string;

    @Column({ collation: "default" })
    lastname: string;

    @Column({ type: "timestamp", default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    created_at?: Date; 

}
```

### What I have tried : I tried to cast field into text to match like operator but does not working.

```
var search_text = "04:45";

var query = this.Account.createQueryBuilder()
            .where('(created_at)::text ilike :search', { search: `%${search_text}%` });
```

Can anyone please guide me , How can I achieve this ?
I am trying to fix it from last two days but still not getting any solution.